# how to join tables by comparing two fields, and also considering performance

Tags: sql, join, hive, teradata

This should be simple but I can't get it. I need to do a select to get newer date values for some accounts.

I start here, T1:

```
+----------+---------+
|  date   | account |
+----------+---------+
| 4/1/2018 |       1 |
| 4/1/2018 |       2 |
| 4/1/2018 |       3 |
| 4/1/2018 |       4 |
| 4/1/2018 |       5 |
+----------+---------+
```

Then some dates are updated in T2:

```
+----------+---------+
|   date   | account |
+----------+---------+
| 7/1/2018 |       1 |
| 7/1/2018 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

How can I get this output into T3, updating just those accounts?

```
+----------+---------+
|   date   | account |
+----------+---------+
| 7/1/2018 |       1 |
| 7/1/2018 |       2 |
| 4/1/2018 |       3 |
| 4/1/2018 |       4 |
| 4/1/2018 |       5 |
+----------+---------+
```

I can do a join on the account number, but what about the ones that didn't change? How to capture those?

Also, T1 has about 8 million records, so performance would be a factor. Extracting from Teradata, loading into Hive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t2.*
from t2
union all
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.account = t1.account);
```

This selects first from `t2`.  Then it takes remaining accounts from `t1`.

Answer (score 8):

Just an addition to previously good answers.. try using it with `coalesce` also and let me know if it improves performance.

```
select t1.Account, coalesce(t2.Date, t1.Date) 
from t1
left outer join t2
  on t2.Account = t1.Account
```

Comment: It will not improve performance over CASE, but it's shorter & cleaner syntax

Comment: I agree, Case is still useful incase you have complex conditions for multiple columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution with left outer join:

```
select t1.Account, case when t2.Date is null then t1.Date else t2.Date end
from t1
left outer join t2 on t2.Account = t1.Account
```